How to intuitively define a Euclidean line?
Here's my definition to intuitively understand a line: "If we start moving from point A in the direction of point B such that at every point in our path we don't change our direction towards B and are able to see point B, the path we follow is called a line." But, this definition can apply to non-Euclidean spaces as well where both space and light might bend. Parallel lines extending infinitely can exist in non-Euclidean spaces as well. Isotropy can exists in non-Eulidean spaces as well. Property that a line is the shortest path between points A and B can exist in non-Euclidean spaces as well. Only one line possible between two points A and B can exist in non-Eucildean spaces as well. Consider a simple non-Euclidean space with a plane having just one "speed breaker" or a "bump" or a "wave" on it. Such a space would satisfy all these conditions. So, how would I define a line such that it adheres to only Euclidean space, i.e., a Euclidean line? I want to avoid using cyclic concepts like curve, bend, distance, etc., to define a line.

As I read it (using established technical terms for precision, and hopefully for clarity), the question is, "How can we characterize -- in naive, non-technical language -- geodesics in Euclidean space in a way that singles out Euclidean space among all Riemannian manifolds?" <> Is this interpretation correct?

I'm confused by this question.  A line can be defined without assuming that it is a subset of a higher dimensional space (Euclidean or not). After that, it is straightforward to define what a curve or line is in a higher dimensional space. If you assume that the Euclidean and non-Euclidean spaces are flat, then the definition of a line is the same for both of them.

I cannot imagine how one could define straightness without appealing to curvature.
